# Corrupt Excel file output using EPPlus in ASP.NET / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

I'm trying to use EPPlus to create a report inside an ASP.NET application. I tried using the code provided into samples package but I'm having some troubles.

The following code is executed without error:

```
        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample1");

        _ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "COD. CONV.";
        _ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        _ws.Cells["A1"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        _ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "RAGIONE SOCIALE";
        _ws.Cells["B1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        _ws.Cells["B1"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        _ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "COMMERCIALE A";
        _ws.Cells["C1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        _ws.Cells["C1"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        _ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "PROVINCIA";
        _ws.Cells["D1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        _ws.Cells["D1"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        _ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "ZONA";
        _ws.Cells["E1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        _ws.Cells["E1"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        _ws.Cells["F1"].Value = "TELEFONO";
        _ws.Cells["F1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        _ws.Cells["F1"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;
        _ws.Cells["G1"].Value = "EMAIL";
        _ws.Cells["G1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        _ws.Cells["G1"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thick;

        int _i = 2;

        foreach (DataRow _drRow in dtAnagrafiche.Rows)
        {
            _ws.Cells["A"+_i.ToString()].Value = _drRow["codice"].ToString();
            _ws.Cells["B"+_i.ToString()].Value = _drRow["Nome"].ToString();
            _ws.Cells["C"+_i.ToString()].Value = "";
            _ws.Cells["D"+_i.ToString()].Value = _drRow["Provincia"].ToString();
            _ws.Cells["E"+_i.ToString()].Value = _drRow["Zona"].ToString();
            _ws.Cells["F"+_i.ToString()].Value = _drRow["Telefono"].ToString();
            _ws.Cells["G"+_i.ToString()].Value = _drRow["Email"].ToString();

            _i++;
        }

        Response.BinaryWrite(_pck.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Lista_Anagrafiche.xlsx");
```

but the resulting file cannot be opened by Microsoft office if not 'recovered', other MS Office compatibile applications (i.e. OpenOffice) cannot open the file.

I can provide the output file if needed.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-lPXYt7laDrbUFKbFZEWEwxckk/view?usp=sharing

BTW I'm using the last (4.0.5) EPPlus package obtained trough nuget, and running it in ASP.NET 4.5 web appplication.

Comment: Sorry no luck even changing `BinaryWrite` call.

Comment: maybe try Response.Clear before Response.BinaryWrite? can you try saving the bytes to a file first to separate the issues between the Excel file output and writing it back through the response? have you tried opening the result file in Notepad?

Comment: @shriop: Opening the file in notepad would be useless, as .xlsx files are compressed as zip files.

Comment: @weirdgyn: You're not doing something write with your response writing. You should run `Response.End()` as well. You're sending the entire binary, then at the very end, the .aspx page is being sent over as well (see screenshot here: http://imgur.com/etE9bPE )

Comment: `Response.Clear()` doesn't fix this issue... you mean to serialize the stream to a file 'on the server' before 'uploading it?
I tried to 'open' the result .xslx file with Microsoft office 'recovering' it and I'm able to see the content (and it seem to be correct) but the file is corrupted in some way I cannot understand. If you try to open the file with other software (OpenOffice) it reports an I/O error. I'm also able to 'upack' the .xslx file as a an archive and the resulting structure look correct also.

Comment: @willaien you're correct! post this as an answer so I can vote it! :-)

Comment: @willaien , I know that it won't open a valid xlsx, my purpose was exactly to see what you suggested, that you might be able to see html written out in the final file confirming that the response writing code was an issue.

Comment: Yes. the issue, in the original code, was due to the postback process that was keeping to run after the `Response` and display the page itself... this  lead to embed the page code inside the `.xslx`... my fault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a call to `Response.End()`. Without this, you're sending the response with the binary payload (the .xlsx file), which is coming over correctly, then the .aspx page that you're coding this under is being sent in the payload as well. [Proof here as shown in a hex editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdp5m.jpg)

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Lista_Anagrafiche.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(_pck.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
```

Should do the trick.

As an aside, I would suggest saving the file, then doing a `Response.Redirect()` to the URL of the file, instead, but that's unrelated to this specific issue.

EDIT: Notably, in normal circumstances, I would suggest avoiding `Response.End()`, but, that is the quickest way to solve the problem you've coded yourself into. I would suggest looking for better ways to serve up these files in general, as per my above suggestion to `Response.Redirect()` to a saved location of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your code to the following notice how I am using the string.Format function to create the filename + extension

you need to declare a constant fileName. if worse comes to worse change the .xlsx to `.xls`

```
Response.Clear();    
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xlsx", fileName));
Response.BinaryWrite(_pck.GetAsByteArray());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thnx! `.xls` is somewhat different from `.xslx`... anyway your suggestion is fine! thnx

Comment: not a problem in your filename I would not hard code it I would use the string.Format function so that it can dynamically create the file so if you wanted to create a file name with the Name and Date etc.. you won't have to hard code it for example 
`public string fileName = "Lista_Anagrafiche_{0}";`
`fileName = string.Format(fileName, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_hhmmss"));` just a suggestion

Comment: my speculation was about changing the file extension with one that was not matching the real content of the file itself... anyway the real code I'm not hardcoding the filename inside the application but I'm generating it at runtime.